# Betweenness centrality calculation for multiple transition matrices

Tags: r, dataframe, igraph

I am a bit lost on how to sort this problem.

As example, I have 2 transition probability matrix that I would like to convert to 2 graphs and to save the betweenness centrality for 2 nodes: 3110 and 110. The results I would like to save in 2 separate csv file. Can this be done using igraph?

I am working with large datasets. How can read into R `n` number of csv files -specific the location of the files- with transition matrices b.) create from each transition matrix a graph; c.) compute specific node betweenness centrality

Sample data

```
df1<-structure(list(X1 = c(110, 111, 210, 300, 310, 390, 1110, 3110, 
3240, 3290, 3310, 3727, 3811, 3819, 3830, 5190, 7241, 7330, 8210, 
9000, 9130, 9380, 9390, 9960), `110` = c(0.939393939, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    `111` = c(0.03030303, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `210` = c(0, 0, 
    0.571428571, 0, 0, 0, 0.025, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `300` = c(0, 0, 0.142857143, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), `310` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.666666667, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `390` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.111111111, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1110` = c(0, 0, 0.142857143, 0, 0, 0, 0.925, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 
    0, 0), `3110` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0.333333333, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `3240` = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0.1, 0, 0), `3290` = c(0.03030303, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0.333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `3310` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.666666667, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `3727` = c(0, 0, 0.142857143, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), `3811` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `3819` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0.166666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0.1, 0, 0), `3830` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0.5, 0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `5190` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.025, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.666666667, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `7241` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.166666667, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), `7330` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `8210` = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.777777778, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1), `9000` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.111111111, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `9130` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0.833333333, 0, 1, 0), `9380` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.025, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.166666667, 0.7, 
    0, 0), `9390` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `9960` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -24L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    X1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector"
    )), `110` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `111` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `210` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `300` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `310` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `390` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `1110` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `3110` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `3240` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `3290` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `3310` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `3727` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `3811` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `3819` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `3830` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `5190` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `7241` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `7330` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `8210` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `9000` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `9130` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `9380` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `9390` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `9960` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))

df2<-structure(list(X1 = c(110, 210, 310, 1110, 3110, 5310, 8210, 
9120, 9390), `110` = c(0.970588235, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.125, 0, 
0), `210` = c(0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0), `310` = c(0.029411765, 
0.25, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1110` = c(0, 0, 0, 0.981481481, 
0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0), `3110` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333, 0.25, 
0, 0, 0.037037037), `5310` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.75, 0, 0, 0.037037037
), `8210` = c(0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0.875, 0, 0), `9120` = c(0, 
0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.75, 0), `9390` = c(0, 0, 0.2, 0.018518519, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.925925926)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(X1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `110` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `210` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `310` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `1110` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `3110` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `5310` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `8210` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `9120` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `9390` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you after this?

```
> g1 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(as.matrix(df1[-1]), weighted = TRUE)

> g2 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(as.matrix(df2[-1]), weighted = TRUE)

> v <- c("3110", "110")

> betweenness(g1, v)
3110  110
  64   22

> betweenness(g2, v)
3110  110
  31    7
```

---

## Update

If you want to save into separate files, perhaps you can try

```
v <- c("3110", "110")
g <- list(g1,g2)
for (i in seq_along(g)) {
    write.csv(between(g[[i]],v),file = paste0("g_",i,".csv"))
}
```

Comment: Yes!!! How can I do this for n number of transition matrixes and to save the betweenness in separate files?

Comment: @user11418708 You can try the code in my updated answer

Comment: @user11418708 and Thomas: Here's something to think about: If the "weights" represent probabilities, as OP states, does it make any sense to use them directly in the computation of _weighted_ betweenness with igraph? (It does not.)

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for your feedback. Yes, you are right. I believe OP will adjust the code to his/her needs.